# How to get childnodes using DOM in Java

Tags: xml, dom

I have this XML.

```
 <employees>
  <employee tag="FT" name="a">
     <password tag="1"/>
     <password tag="2"/>
</employee>
<employee tag="PT" name="b">
     <password tag="3"/>
     <password tag="4"/>
</employee>
</employees>
```

I am trying to get the child nodes of each employee and put the tag value of child nodes i.e. 
password's tag value in a list.

```
nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

for(int i=0;i<nl.getLength();i++){
 NamedNodeMap nnm = nl.item(i).getAttributes(); 
 NodeList children = nl.item(i).getChildNodes();
 passwordList = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(int j=0; j<children.getLength();j++){
   NamedNodeMap n = children.item(j).getAttributes();
   passwordTagAttr=(Attr) n.getNamedItem("tag");
   passwordTag=stopTagAttr.getValue();  
   passwordList.add(passwordTag);                   
   }
}
```

I am getting value of  children =4 when I debug. But I should be getting it 2 for each loop 
Please help.

Comment: <employees>
      <employee tag="FT" name="a">
         <password tag="1"/>
         <password tag="2"/>
    </employee>
    <employee tag="PT" name="b">
         <password tag="3"/>
         <password tag="4"/>
   </employee>
 </employees>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the `NodeList` returned by `getChildNodes()` contains `Element` child nodes (which is what you care about in this case) as well as attribute child nodes of the `Node` itself (which you don't).

```
for(int j=0; j<children.getLength();j++) {
   if (children.item(j) instanceof Element == false)
       continue;

   NamedNodeMap n = children.item(j).getAttributes();
   passwordTagAttr=(Attr) n.getNamedItem("tag");
   passwordTag=stopTagAttr.getValue();  
   passwordList.add(passwordTag);                   
}
```